# Display <div></div> inside expandable accordion - doesn't show what's inside <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an expanding accordion. But when adding a  inside the  area, the div does not show, but only displays as blank? Any ideas? Thanks.

How can I get the div inside the  to display its content?

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/6xnt3p8j/1/

JavaScript

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".accordion2 h3").eq(40).addClass("active");
        $(".accordion2 p").eq(40).show();
        $(".accordion2 h3").click(function(){
        var video = $(".accordion2 h3.active").next().children();
        var src = video.attr("src");
        video.attr("src","");
        video.attr("src",src);

        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow")
        .siblings("div:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 570px;
    font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

.accordion2 {
     min-height:95px;
     height:auto !important;
     height:95px;

}

.accordion2 h3 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height:95px;
    height:auto !important;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.accordion2 h3:hover {
    background-color: #e3e2e2;
}
.accordion2 h3.active {
    background-position: right 5px;
}
.accordion2 div {
/*    background: red;
*/    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion2">

    <h3>
        <div class="box"><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/tPgf_btTFlc'>
        </div>
    </h3>
    <div>text text text text text text text text</div>

    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>text text text text text text text text</div>

    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>text text text text text text text text</div>



</div>
```

Thanks a million /M

Comment: You can't put a `div` element inside an `h3` anyway as it is invalid HTML.

Comment: If its just for an image, style the H3 (background-image:url(..))

Comment: Thanks for replies. I am looking to put three images next to each other, and when clicked, the accordion expands... If I can't put a div inside the h3, is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

remove **display: none;** in the css

Here is your css file

```
body {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 570px;
    font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px auto;
}

.accordion2 {
     min-height:95px;
     height:auto !important;
     height:95px;

}

.accordion2 h3 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height:95px;
    height:auto !important;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.accordion2 h3:hover {
    background-color: #e3e2e2;
}
.accordion2 h3.active {
    background-position: right 5px;
}
.accordion2 div {
/*    background: red;
*/    margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3575812, yes that actually works. However the whole accordion shows in an expanded state then.. how do I keep the accordion closed (opens only when clicked)? Thanks

Comment: You can see the display: none code here removed. Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/6xnt3p8j/8/

Comment: thanks. Yes, it worked. but the acccordion is in expanded mode? I would like it to expand when clicked. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I use Chrome btw. Thanks